# Entity Framework 6.1.3: Projection - load children of children directly

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, projection, anonymous-types

My objective is to make only one trip to the database, and get Orders with a filtered child collection.

To achieve this, I've used a projection:

```
using (var db = new context())
            {
                var query = from o in db.Orders
                           select
                               new
                               {
                                   Order = o,
                                   Events = o.Events.Where(
                                       e => e.SomeBool 
                                       && e.SomeBool2
                                   ),

                                   EventsGroups = o.Events.Where(
                                       e => e.SomeBool 
                                       && e.SomeBool2
                                   ).Select(e => e.Groups),

                               };
            }
```

The issue here is that the child collection, "Groups" on events, is not loaded. To solve this, I have loaded it as another property "EventsGroups" in the query, which I can then put together with the Events afterwards.

**My Question:** Is there a way to load the child, "Groups" onto the "Event" directly, so I do not have to get them as another property?

Along the lines of

```
Events = o.Events.Where(
e => e.SomeBool 
&& e.SomeBool2
).Include(e => e.Groups), //this cannot be done this way
```

---

Why am i using a projection and not eager loading:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/hh205756.aspx

[Filtering include items in LINQ and Entity Framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25629022/filtering-include-items-in-linq-and-entity-framework)

The underlying classes:

```
public class Order
{
    public Order()
    {
        Events = new HashSet<Event>();
    }

    public int Id { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Event> Events { get; set; }
}

public class Event
{
    public Event()
    {
        Groups = new HashSet<Group>();
    }

    public int Id { get; set; }

    public bool SomeBool { get; set; }

    public bool SomeBool2 { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Group> Groups { get; set; }
}

public class Group
{
    public Group()
    {
        Events = new HashSet<Event>();
    }

    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Event> Events { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: can you try `o.Events.include(e => e.Groups).Where(...` ?

Comment: Do you mean inside the projection? I do not believe Include exists there http://imgur.com/ZOOXx0E

Comment: sorry you're right I think @Ivans answer below should work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since `Include` cannot be combined with anonymous projection, you need to project `Event.Groups` the same way you project `Order.Events`, i.e. using another anonymous type projection:

```
var query = from o in db.Orders
            select new
            {
                Order = o,
                Events = (from e in o.Events
                          where e.SomeBool && e.SomeBool2
                          select new
                          {
                              Event = e,
                              Groups = e.Groups,
                          }),
            };
```

Comment: This is much more beatiful than my way of doing it, and easier to put together. I suspect this is a close as I can get to avoiding loops to construct the DTO objects from the anynomous objects.

Comment: If you do have a DTO objects, you can project directly to them instead of anonymous types - EF supports that.

Answer (score 0):

you can to load everything by setting     `Configuration.LazyLoadingEnabled = true;` ,  without need for any Include , of course... perfoamnce must set in mind.. depends..

```
    public MyDatabaseContext(string databaseName)
        : base(databaseName)
    {
        Configuration.LazyLoadingEnabled = true;
    }
```

Comment: This breaks with my objective of only having one trip to the database

Answer (score 0):

I believe this should work for you:

```
using (var db = new context())
{
  var query = db.Orders
    .Include(o=>o.Events)
    .Include(o=>o.Events.Select(e=>e.Groups))
    .Select(o=>new
    {
      Order = o,
      Events = o.Events.Where(e => e.SomeBool && e.SomeBool2)
    });
}
```

if not, this will:

```
using (var db = new context())
{
  var query = db.Orders
    .Include(o=>o.Events)
    .Include(o=>o.Events.Select(e=>e.Groups))
    .Select(o=>new Order
    {
      Id=o.Id,
      Events = o.Events.Where(e => e.SomeBool && e.SomeBool2).ToList()
    });
}
```

Comment: This did not work while testing. Groups did not get loaded. Getting orders and the filtered events works, but there is just an empty list for groups on the events. The includes do not seems to be doing anything, as it is the same result with or without them.

Comment: Hmm.  Interesting.  A simple fix is to add `.ToList()` between the Include and Select.  That will definitely work, however, you will be retrieving all the event records, not just ones that match your `.Where` conditions.