# Lambda Expression to filter Included Entities

Tags: c#, linq, lambda, entity-framework-core

I have this query,

```
var productCategories = _dbContext
   .Set<ProductCategory>()
   .Include(x => x.ProductInCategories)
   .ThenInclude(x => x.Product)
   .ThenInclude(x => x.ProductMetadatas)
   .Where(x => x.Active)
   .ToList();
```

But, I can't filter products in this query. I just want to have the Active Products. Any Help will be appreciated.

Comment: _Active_ property is in `Porducts` or `ProductCategory`?

Comment: Active property is in Product

Comment: Something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25629226/492258)

Comment: This has been asked many times. Filtered includes never been (and still isn't) supported. EF Core 2.0 supports [Model-level query filters](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/what-is-new/#model-level-query-filters), but they apply for every query.